# What does it mean by too few arguments to function 'addBook'?

Tags: c, file, data-structures

> I'm basically trying to add a book into my libraryy.txt file my problem is the compiler says that there's too few arguments to perform the addBook() function, what should I include in the addBook() function parentheses in my main function?

```
struct book{
         char *title;
         char *author;
         char *subject;
};

struct library {
    struct book collection;
    int num_books;
    struct library *next;
};
```

This is my addBook() function:

```
void addBook(struct library* thislib){
FILE *cfPtr;
cfPtr = fopen("libraryy.txt", "a");
char strtitle[MAX];
char strauthor[MAX];
char strsubject[MAX];
int operation;
struct library acollection;
        printf("Title: ");
        scanf("%s", strtitle); 
        printf("Author: ");
        scanf("%s", strauthor);
        printf("Subject: ");
        scanf("%s", strsubject);
        thislib->collection.title = strtitle;
        thislib->collection.author = strauthor;
        thislib->collection.subject = strsubject;
        printf("The book %s author %s subject %s has been added to the library.\n", thislib->collection.title, thislib->collection.author, thislib->collection.subject);

       fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %s %s\n", operation, collection.title, collection.author, collection.subject);

}
```

> The compiler is telling me that there are too few arguments to perform function addBook..what should I add in the parentheses for addBook?? The error is in my main method below:

```
 FILE *cfPtr;
int operation;



 if ((cfPtr = fopen("libraryy.txt","a")) == NULL){
        printf("File could not be opened...\n");
    }

   else {


        while(1){
        operate();
        printf("Enter an operation: ");
        scanf("%d", &operation);

        switch(operation){
            case 1:
            addBook(); //it basically gave me the error here which is 'too few arguments to perform function addBook'
           break;
```

> Don't get me wrong, I know what does too few arguments/no arguments mean but what should I include in those parentheses as arguments? :") Need some help.

Comment: Give us an idea what you are trying to achieve with the addBook() function

Comment: I want to add a book's title author and subject into my libraryy.txt file by entering that particular book's title, author and subject into my compiler's screen. Also that book's title, author & subject should not only be then reflected as a data in my libraryy.txt file when I open that file but as an output on the compiler's screen as well to let the user acknowledge that his/her book has been added into the file (or in other words, the libraryy.txt file). @Blue_Hat

Comment: You wrote the `addBook()` function to take a parameter. What did you intend this parameter to be? (It looks like it's the library you want to add the book to.) Whatever that parameter is supposed to be, the function call in `main()` should pass that thing the parameter is supposed to be.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I don't get it, like am I supposed to write it like addBook(struct book collection) or something?

Comment: You wrote the `addBook` function! Tell us what you had in mind when you wrote `void addBook(struct library* thislib)`.